# Media Queries on Safari in Windows not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

It seems that this is a common problem, but I don´t get it fixed.

I´ve tried adding min-width, didn´t work, then I tried a max-width approach, and I get working only that media query. The next media queries doesn´t get working.

What could I do? How should I write the media queries?

I want a media query to get 334px min-width, and so forth.

Thanks.

I have two sizes queries.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width:334px)  { 
 html.safari  div#wrapper {
 background-color: gray;
 border: 32px solid transparent;
}
}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width:434px)  { 
 html.safari  div#wrapper {
 background-color: gray;
 border: 52px solid transparent;
}
}
```

I get only the last query when I am at 334px width.

Comment: I´ve tried adding this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> Didn´t work

Comment: The version of Safari I´m using is 5.1.7.

Comment: use <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Hi. Sorry I´ve added your meta and it doesn´t work also. I´ve tried to add this media query: @media all and (min-width: 334px) { } Doesnt´work

Comment: Safari for Windows (last version 5.1.7) was last updated in 2012. Apple doesn't support it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code all the time and havent had a problem yet. https://jsfiddle.net/mlegg10/xr2rnq15/

```css
/*
  Based on:
  1. http://stephen.io/mediaqueries
  2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
*/

/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* 
  iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
  It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.
*/

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {
  
}

/* iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  
}

/* iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  
}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S3 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S4 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 320px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Galaxy S5 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* HTC One portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

}

/* HTC One portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* HTC One landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/*
  iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries
  If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads 
  (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics,
  or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries.
*/

/* Retina iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/* Retina iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  
}

/*
  iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries
  If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography 
  for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work 
  like a charm in your responsive design!
*/

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* iPad mini in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* iPad mini in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait and landscape */
@media
  (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 800px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Galaxy Tab 10.1 landscape */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait and landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 portrait */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

}

/* Asus Nexus 7 landscape */
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 601px) 
  and (device-height: 906px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 7" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 800px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait and landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {
    
}

/* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* Laptops non-retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    
}

/* Laptops retina screens */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    
}

/* Apple Watch */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

}

/* Moto 360 Watch */
@media 
  (max-device-width: 218px)
  and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

}
```

Comment: That is nice, I think I´m gonna substitute min-width for min-device-width

Comment: I´m searching for a simpler answer. I´ve tried to add min-device-width. Again, I get only one media query. I´ve tried to add another media query width a greater width, and it just don´t work. It overwrites the minor width query

Comment: Did you add all of that css to the end of your existing code, but get rid of the responsive media queries you have now? Try it and save it as a styles2.css (or add a 2 to whatever your style sheet is called) and then edit an html page to says 2.css and try it out.

Comment: Remove other media query from the code? Add these media queries to another css file?

Comment: I'm basically saying to make a copy of your home page and your css sheet. Then when you mess around with the changes, you will not be messing up your original files. If you want post a link to your online page here.

Comment: If it might help: I've found out that `min-device-width`and `max-device-width` are currently ignored in my project; switching to `max-width` and `min-width` is understood